# Using ApiExplorerSettings GroupName in Route in ASPNET Core

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-3.1, asp.net-core-routing, asp.net-mvc-apiexplorer, aspnet-api-versioning

In ASP.NET Core - Web API project

Using `[ApiExplorerSettings(GroupName = "<group-name>")]` decorated on ApiController
and in `[Route]` attribute I want to refer above `GroupName` property value.

Also note I do have `[ApiVersion("<some-version>")]` on same controller to classify further.

Here are some samples to explain:

Example 1:

Attribute on LeadController: `[ApiVersion("1.0"), ApiExplorerSettings(GroupName = "sales"), [Route("api/{groupName}/v{version:apiVersion}/leads"]`

Expected translated route format: `/api/sales/v1/leads`

Attribute on AccountsController: `[ApiVersion("2.1"), ApiExplorerSettings(GroupName = "finance"), [Route("api/{groupName}/v{version:apiVersion}/accounts"]`

Expected translated route format: `/api/finance/v2.1/leads`

In above `{version:apiVersion}` gives me `ApiVersion` value (I assume because that attribute has ToString set to version value). But when I try `{groupName}` or `{grp:groupName}` or `{grp:ApiExplorerSettings.GroupName}` - none of them works. How can access this group name in route attribute?

Answer (score 2):

Do you have any special settings somewhere else, it works fine on my side.

**LeadController:**

```
[ApiVersion("1.0"), ApiExplorerSettings(GroupName = "sales"),Route("api/{groupName}/v{version:apiVersion}/leads")]
[ApiController]
public class LeadController : ControllerBase
{
    public string Get()
    {
        return "sales group";
    }
}
```

**AccountsController:**

```
[ApiVersion("2.1"), ApiExplorerSettings(GroupName = "finance"), Route("api/{groupName}/v{version:apiVersion}/accounts")]
[ApiController]
public class AccountsController : ControllerBase
{
    public string Get()
    {
        return "finance group";
    }
}
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: That is correct - I didn't try that way - but the issue is I still see the un-replaced {groupName} when I see the same endpoint in Swagger UI page configured in the project - any idea why? Thanks for the help though. E.g. When seeing in swagger I see `/api/{groupName}/v1.0/leads`

Answer (score 0):

`ApiExplorerSettings.GroupName` is **only** for the logical group name used in API descriptions. It is **not** used or evaluated in route templates. There is no way to make that work. That is why it never expands. It is possible to use a `{groupName}` route parameter, but it will be just that - a route parameter.

It's not entirely clear if you are trying to control grouping for the API Explorer or use a route parameter. Grouping is typically used by the API Explorer. API Versioning will assign or override the group name so that APIs are bucketized by their version. It is possible to change this behavior, but you'll need an API Explorer (via **IApiDescriptionProvider**) or OpenAPI/Swagger document generator extension to do it.

Comment: I am honestly not sure what you mean by "It is not used or evaluated in route templates. There is no way to make that work." - But I am able to find that in ActionDescriptor - Endpoint Route details - issue was it does not get picked up the way I thought in Swagger JSON to create seperate OpenAPI json per group name - which I found after mj1313 gave a hint towards the same - Now I added my custom swagger logic to do the same. All good now, thanks for the help

Comment: Correct. Glad you got it working. All I was saying is that `ApiExplorerSettings.GroupName != {groupName}`. In fact, you don't even need `{groupName}` with the way you have things. You can use `ApiExplorerSettings.GroupName` to group in a OpenAPI document, but that is independent of `{groupName}`. I would recommend getting rid of `{groupName}` and just using `finance` and `sales` literals in your route template (based on your example)

Comment: Agreed and you are not wrong at all - but I have 4-5 such group-names to manage and coach the team to use it right - so with the goal that they do not mis-spell it or run into problems - I am have created fixed monikers that are mapped back with groupName so they follow the templating vs hard coding the keyword in the route template.